# Un-awarded bounty refunded on deleting post

Tags: support, deleted-questions, bounties

I created a question a month or two ago that didn't attract much attention, in hindsight it wasn't really meant for Drupal Answers (It was about a whole mess of LDAP and kerberos stuff).

I set a bounty of 50 rep in the hopes of attracting some help, nobody answered (fact, not a complaint).

I decided to delete the post because it added nothing to the site and was able to do so easily, again no problem.

Surprisingly, my bounty was refunded.  My questions are thus:

- Is the bounty supposed to be refunded in these circumstances? and
- What happens if there are answers?
- What happens if there is an awarded bounty?

I ask out of concern that people might rort the system by deleting useful posts to recover rep.

Comment: Surprising bounty is like advertising cost, u r lucky, looks like bug!

Comment: You cant delete if it has answer

Comment: As @bala said, this only works because you got no answers. As soon as there are answers posted, you can't remove the question anymore without the help of a mod.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240502/how-does-deletion-affect-previous-unawarded-bounties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading [SO points changed (+50) for no reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172556/so-points-changed-50-for-no-reason), which was marked [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) from a Stack Exchange developer, I get it is what normally happen when a question has been deleted.

As for gaming the system, keep in mind that users cannot delete their own questions with up-voted answers. In the case they would keep doing it with answered questions (where the answer has a score of 0 or negative) for which they offered a bounty, diamonds moderators would get notified about consecutive deleted questions, and would investigate.

Answer (score 3):

As @bala said in comments, this only works because you got no answers. As soon as there are answers posted, you can't remove the question anymore without the help of a mod.

So I don't think there's a way to "cheat the system" here.